# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to call function on prototype

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

This was an interesting swift problem I ran into. Consider the following class and protocol:

```
class Person {

}

protocol Parent where Self: Person {
    func speak()
}

class GrandMotherPerson: Person, Parent {
    func speak() {
        print("I am a Grandmother Person")
    }
}

class GrandFatherPerson: Person, Parent {
    func speak() {
        print("I am a Grandfather Person")
    }
}

let gmp = GrandMotherPerson()
let gfp = GrandFatherPerson()
```

Now when you call

```
gmp.speak() // Output: I am a Grandmother Person
gfp.speak() // Output: I am a Grandfather Person
```

But if you cast to Parent

```
(gmp as Parent).speak() // EXC_BAD_ACCESS when it should say "I am a Grandmother Person"
```

but if I `print(String(describing: gmp))`it says it's a `__lldb_expr_226.GrandMotherPerson`

Why can't swift call `speak` on the class? If you remove the `where Self: Person` from the protocol then it works as expected.

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-55 ? Sorry if not; I find the issue rather confusing so I could be wrong.

Comment: @matt I'm not sure that it is the same bug; but even if it is, it probably deserves its own report as a Swift program shouldn't crash from a mere method call (I'll file one in a sec).  From a quick look at the code generated by the compiler, it's mis-compiling the program (it's basically trying to treat an `UnsafePointer<Person>` as a `Person`). In the latest dev snapshot, an assertion actually gets triggered on compiling, which I guess is *slightly* better, but it needs fixing.

Comment: Bug filed: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6816

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for doing that. I find the existential-related bugs very confusing, as I said. As I said in my note on my answer, something very odd is going on because we get two different results depending on whether you say `let parent = gmp as Parent; parent.speak()` or `(gmp as Parent).speak()` even though they should do the same thing.

Comment: @matt Yeah that definitely doesn't sound right; though I can't reproduce it in either 4.0.3 or 4.1-dev. In the examples you give in your answer, I get the same results in each for both `(gmp as Parent).speak()` & `let parent = gmp as Parent; parent.speak()` (first example prints `"I am a Grandmother Person"`, second example EXC_BAD_ACCESSes). What version of Swift are you using?

Comment: @Hamish It was in a playground using Xcode 9.2; if there is something more recent, I don't have it. Of course I could just be mistaken. :)

Comment: thanks for filling the bug!

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure this is the same deep issue discussed at length at https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-55. Consider that this compiles and runs just fine:

```
class Person : NSObject {}
@objc protocol Parent where Self: Person {
    func speak()
}
class GrandMotherPerson: Person, Parent {
    func speak() {
        print("I am a Grandmother Person")
    }
}
let gmp = GrandMotherPerson()
let parent = gmp as Parent
parent.speak() // I am a Grandmother Person
```

But now delete `@objc` and we get the same issue you're having:

```
class Person : NSObject {}
protocol Parent where Self: Person {
    func speak()
}
class GrandMotherPerson: Person, Parent {
    func speak() {
        print("I am a Grandmother Person")
    }
}
let gmp = GrandMotherPerson()
let parent = gmp as Parent
parent.speak() // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

So if it's the same issue, the Swift team are very well aware of it, but it runs deep and is difficult to fix. The workaround for now is to use `@objc` as in my first example.

**NOTE** I have deliberately separated your last statement into two. That's because there seems to be a further issue with saying `(gmp as Parent).speak()` - apparently we need an actual variable reference to the existential rather than an implicit temporary.

Comment: I don't know why, putting `where Self: Person` into protocol `extension` also works. I have tested on Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.